# I need finrl 0.3.1 version repo

Tags: python, reinforcement-learning, quantconnect, finrl

There is a `finrl=0.3.1` which is used by quantconnect platform. I want to check that file and contents repository. Where should I get all this file?
[found on quantconnect docs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ADDzh.png)
I searched on github but there is not a release for `0.3.1`.

[finrl github release](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t4tPf.png)

I'm working on quantconnect which supports only finrl 0.3.1 version so I need specific version please help to get this.

Comment: according to release history ver 0.3.1 was released on 5 Sept 2021. Also confirmed by commit history. You can browse the repo at this point of time/specific commit.

Comment: This is [the repo](https://github.com/AI4Finance-Foundation/FinRL/tree/52656e6dc9016857963d2dd2a5a99d57e95d61fd) as of latest commit (52656e6dc9016857963d2dd2a5a99d57e95d61fd) of `setup.py` on 5 Sept 2021 Check history for more details